# Are there any plans to make the Developer Survey results available in a PDF or print-friendly format?

Tags: feature-request, survey

I'm not sure if anyone has requested this before, but I was wondering if the Developer survey results would be made available in PDF or some other format to download and/or print?  Trying to cut n paste it doesn't seem to work very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have any plans to create a PDF version in 2019. We will release the results online only.